# Best way to emulate Ruby "splat" operator in PHP function signatures [Method overloading]

Tags: php, ruby, overloading

### In Ruby

```
def my_func(foo,bar,*zim)
  [foo, bar, zim].collect(&:inspect)
end

puts my_func(1,2,3,4,5)

# 1
# 2
# [3, 4, 5]
```

### In PHP (5.3)

```
function my_func($foo, $bar, ... ){
  #...
}
```

What's the best way to to do this in PHP?

Comment: have a look at func_get_args()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

- [`func_get_args`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list

PHP Version of your Ruby Snippet

```
function my_func($foo, $bar)
{
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    return array(
        array_shift($arguments),
        array_shift($arguments),
        $arguments
    );
}
print_r( my_func(1,2,3,4,5,6) );
```

or just

```
function my_func($foo, $bar)
{
    return array($foo , $bar , array_slice(func_get_args(), 2));
}
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )
)
```

Note that `func_get_args()` will return all arguments passed to a function, not just those not in the signature. Also note that any arguments you define in the signature are considered required and PHP will raise a Warning if they are not present.

If you only want to get the *remaining* arguments and determine that at runtime, you could use the [ReflectionFunction API](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) to read the number of arguments in the signature and [`array_slice`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the full list of arguments to contain only the additional ones, e.g.

```
function my_func($foo, $bar)
{
    $rf = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
    $splat = array_slice(func_get_args(), $rf->getNumberOfParameters());
    return array($foo, $bar, $splat);
}
```

Why anyone would want that over just using `func_get_args()` is beyond me, but it would work. More straightforward is accessing the arguments in any of these ways:

```
echo $foo;
echo func_get_arg(0); // same as $foo
$arguments = func_get_args();
echo $arguments[0]; // same as $foo too
```

If you need to document variable function arguments, [PHPDoc suggest to use](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html)

```
/**
 * @param Mixed $foo Required
 * @param Mixed $bar Required
 * @param Mixed, ... Optional Unlimited variable number of arguments
 * @return Array
 */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Gordon, the splat collects all the overloaded params into an array. I was afraid PHP was going to have to hurl on itself to get this type of functionality...

Comment: You don't even need $foo and $bar in the function definition, other than for "documentation" purposes - function my_func() would suffice - though if $foo and $bar are in the function definition they can be referenced as such in the function code.

Comment: @macek well, PHP does not have a facility to only collect the overloaded params, but `func_get_args` will contain any arguments passed to a function independent from it's signature. In the above function `$foo` and `$bar` makes these two required arguments. PHP will raise an error if you do not supply them. Inside the function it's `$foo is func_get_arg(0) is func_get_args()[0]`

Comment: @macek just split the resulting array into the variables you want using something like list($foo, $baz, $baz) = array().  http://us3.php.net/list  Also, you're bound to get more useful answers when you don't hurl on someone's chosen platform.

Comment: @Alan, I wasn't intending to hurl on PHP; I use it all the time. PHP just isn't very suitable for meta programming.

Answer (score 10):

Copying my answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300835/variadic-functions-and-type-hinting-in-php/21386915#21386915) related to this:

> This is now [possible with PHP 5.6.x](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics), using the ... operator (also
>   known as splat operator in some languages):
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> function addDateIntervalsToDateTime( DateTime $dt, DateInterval ...$intervals )
> {
>     foreach ( $intervals as $interval ) {
>         $dt->add( $interval );
>     }
>     return $dt;
> }
> ```