# Variadic functions and type-hinting in PHP

Tags: php, types, variadic-functions, type-hinting

Quick one:

Is there any way to enforce types for variadic functions in PHP? I'm assuming not, however maybe I've missed something.

As of now, I'm just forcing a single required argument of the needed type, and iterating to check the rest.

```
public function myFunction(MyClass $object){
    foreach(func_get_args() as $object){
        if(!($object instanceof MyClass)){
            // throw exception or something
        }
        $this->_objects[] = $object;
    }
}
```

Any better solutions?

---

Purpose:

A container object that acts as an iterated list of the child objects, with some utility functions. calling it with a variadic constructor would be something like this:

```
// returned directly from include
return new MyParent(
    new MyChild($params),
    new MyChild($params),
    new MyChild($params)
);
```

The other option could be an `addChild` method chain:

```
$parent = new MyParent;
return $parent
    ->addChild(new MyChild($params))
    ->addChild(new MyChild($params))
    ->addChild(new MyChild($params));
```

The children take several arguments to their constructor as well, so I'm trying to balance between legibility and processing expense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would say it depends on the number of arguments :) There is nothing like a list (all arguments 1-n as MyClass [before PHP 5.6, for PHP 5.6+ see [Variadic functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics)]), it's more that you need to write each argument (as in your question) and it's allowed to send more but only the ones defined will be checked.

However you can define more and make them optional. Hence why I just wrote it depends on the number of arguments:

```
public function myFunction(MyClass $object, MyClass $object2=null, MyClass $object3=null, MyClass $object4=null, ...){
    foreach(func_get_args() as $object){
        if(null === $object){
            // throw exception or something
        }
        $this->_objects[] = $object;
    }
}
```

With such an example, PHP would have thrown the exception already when the argument is not NULL and not MyClass (Passing NULL if given as default value, [is possible](http://ch2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting) to pass as well). Optional parameter should not be part of the return value of `func_get_args()`. I mean, if you don't pass the third argument (here named `$object3`) it won't appear in the array returned by [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/function.func-get-args).

No idea if that is more practicable for you than your the code in the question.

If you face more such situations in your code, you can create some sort of helper to validate the input of function calls and delegate to throw the exceptions with nice error message from the helper. That will prevent duplicate code and will give more comfort in development as you can make the exception notices nicer as you write them for multiple cases.

---

According to your new feedback, if you want first of all the interpreter let the work of checking, a little iteration and the addMember function would do it:

```
class MyParent {
    private $children = array();
    public function __construct() {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $object) $this->addChild($object);
    }
    public function addChild(MyChild $object) {
        $this->children[] = $object;
    }
}
```

Instantiating the object with a wrong type of object in any of the list will prevent the Collection to be instantiated.

you can then just do this:

```
// returned directly from include
return new MyParent(
    new MyChild($params),
    new MyChild($params),
    new MyChild($params)
);
```

Comment: Thanks **hakre**; My intended use is for passing a non-finite number of objects of a given class, and the number is always arbitrary. The object constructor to which they're being passed is for a container object, but all children must be of the appropriate class. The other option I'm considering is method chaining an `addObject` method; I may end up going that route for semantics, though calling a (possibly) huge number of `addObject` methods could be expensive, which is why I initially opted for a variadic constructor. Examples added to question.

Comment: TomcatExodus, I added some examplary code which spares you to throw exceptions as PHP will do it for you. But in any case there will be some sort of iteration necessary if you want to perform checks. Albeit I think there might be something in SPL as a typed list which might handle this.

Comment: Thanks again **hakre**; My concern now is the cost associated with calling `addChild()` for each argument from the constructor, or as a chainable method. *Micro-optimization*, I know; however there may be circumstances where that approach could prove less than ideal. I'm going to have to benchmark when I have the chance; if there's a noticeable loss of performance from the chained methods I'll go with the constructor approach, leaving the chain-able method for post-instantiation additions. Most of the children are set at instantiation anyways, and returned from an include as in my example.

Comment: I can't say if that is MO or not, depends what you do. However I don't know how many thousand objects you have, but iteration works fast. If you don't need to check the type of the children, just assign them to the array. You could add the iterator later on if you still know what you were doing :)

Comment: I considered that, performing the check on access rather than on initialization. Really, if the wrong object is added, its an exception fatal to the application; a complete misfire on behalf of the client-programmer (*it's a framework I'm working on*) therefore, performing the check for each child at initialization may be sub-optimal anyways. The parent container implements `Iterator` for quick access, I could drop the check into `current()`. Much to consider. Thanks again **hakre**, I'll let this question sit for a bit just to see if anyone else has insight.

Comment: `next()` is a place as well. I would say it really depends if lazy type checking is useful in your case or not. I normally tend to signal fatal problems as early as possible. It's a bit more work for coders in the beginning but on the other hand the code is cleaner and normally more robust to use. So the client programmer will see the mistakes made directly and not later on while iterating which might be much later in the programs flow.

Answer (score 23):

This is now [possible with PHP 5.6.x](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics), using the ... operator (also known as splat operator in some languages):

Example:

```
function addDateIntervalsToDateTime( DateTime $dt, DateInterval ...$intervals )
{
    foreach ( $intervals as $interval ) {
        $dt->add( $interval );
    }
    return $dt;
}
```

Comment: in PHP7 is also possible to type hint using scalar types.